# How do I calculate the peak output voltage of a capacitor differentiator?

Tags: capacitor

How do I calculate the peak output voltage of a capacitor differentiator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean like this?

[image]

The peak output voltage would just be the peak input voltage.  If it changes fast enough, the output will track it almost exactly, and then decay to smaller values:

[image]

Oh wait.  That doesn't take into account a repeating waveform, like this:

[image]

After the wave has decayed, when you switch the input again, the output will jump to a lower voltage than the input:

[image]

So I think the worst case would be square waves of low frequency, so that they decay completely to zero before switching, and the peak-to-peak output voltage would then be 2× the input peak-to-peak voltage.